# Show point, based on coordinates, on a map in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I would like to enter coordinates (e.g. UTM longitude 323519 & UTM latitude 3777727) by hand into QGIS and have it identify that point (either by centering the map on that point or, better yet, by putting a marker at the corresponding location on the map).

I know how to generate a CSV file with coordinates but don't want to go through the process of generating a CSV file each time I want to find a location on a map.

Seems like a simple question but I have been struggling to find an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to install a QGIS plugin if you don't like the CSV file import option.

There are the [NumericalDigitize](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/numericalDigitize/) and the [NumericalVertexEdit](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/numericalVertexEdit/) plugin which do exactly this.